# Windows ping chooses IPv4 address

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, ipv6

When I run `ping myserver` I can see two DNS queries in Wireshark, one for A and one for AAAA. Both get answered with the IPv4 and IPv6 address respectively and `ping` starts pinging the IPv4 address. If I run `ping -6` it uses the IPv6 address.

I thought IPv6 is preferred if both are available, why does it choose IPv4?

I have an IPv6 address and a default IPv6 route with the link-local address of my router. That said, the internet is not reachable through this route, but ping (or the DNS resolver) doesn't know that, does it?

Comment: does the system you are pinging from have a routable ipv6?

Comment: and if it does, how similar are the source and destination addresses? do they share a common prefix? are any of them ULA or site-local? "source address selection" (netsh int ipv6 show prefixpolicy) may be preferring native ipv4 over e.g. ULA ipv6 or "6to4" ipv6

Comment: Yes, the system I'm pinging has a normal internet IPv6 address and can be pinged from locations with IPv6 connectivity just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the `ping` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping) does not specify defaults nor precedence; just that either IPv4 or IPv6 could be forced when the target is a hostname.

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `/4` | Specifies IPv4 used to ping. This parameter is not required to identify the target host with an IPv4 address. It is only required to identify the target host by name. |
| `/6` | Specifies IPv6 used to ping. This parameter is not required to identify the target host with an IPv6 address. It is only required to identify the target host by name. |

The precedence comes from the **prefix policies**, e.g.,

```
C:\> netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies

Precedence Label Prefix
---------- ----- ------
        50     0 ::1/128
        40     1 ::/0
        35     4 ::ffff:0:0/96
        30     2 2002::/16
         5     5 2001::/32
         3    13 fc00::/7
         1    11 fec0::/10
         1    12 3ffe::/16
         1     3 ::/96
```

If the `::/0` has higher precedence than the `::ffff:0:0/96` (IPv4), then IPv6 is preferred, and vice versa.

From the article "[Guidance for configuring IPv6 in Windows for advanced users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows)" you can also see that there is a registry key for configuring IPv6. The table is shortened.

> The IPv6 functionality can be configured by modifying the following registry key:
>
> Location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\`
> Name: `DisabledComponents`
> Type: `REG_DWORD`
> Min Value: `0x00` (default value)
> Max Value: `0xFF` (IPv6 disabled)
>
> | IPv6 Functionality | Registry value and comments |
> | --- | --- |
> | Prefer IPv4 over IPv6 | Decimal `32` Hexadecimal `0x20` Binary `xx1x xxxx` Recommended instead of disabling IPv6. |
> | Prefer IPv6 over IPv4 | Binary `xx0x xxxx` |